# Definition of a topological space via neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, definition

By definition we have:

> A subset $V$ of a topological space $X$ is a neighborhood of a set $S$ contained in $X$ if and only if $V$ is a neighborhood of every points in $S$.

On the other hand from the definition of a topological space (from the axiomatization due to Felix Hausdorff) using the concept of neighborhoods we have that:

> If $V$ is a neighborhood of a set $S$ then it contains a neighborhood $U$ of $S$ such that $V$ is a neighborhood for each point contained in $U$

I am asking if the first claim does have any proof or is true just by the definition from the second one?

Comment: Something here seems amiss. The second statement is trivial as you can choose $U=V$. I suggest you verify that both texts define "neighborhood" the same, in particular, pay attention to which sets are assumed to be open/closed.

Comment: @ShaiDeshe the first one is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics) and the second is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space

Comment: It can be dangerous to mix and match definitions across different sources, for example when mixing and matching amongst two different web pages from a crowd sourced reference such as wikipedia. Mathematical terminology is less consistent that one might wish it to be, and historically the terminology of a "neighborhood" in topology is quite inconsistent.

Comment: @LeeMosher, have you ever seen any proof from the first one?

Comment: That is not a definition of a neighborhood.  It is the definition of an open neighborhood.

Comment: [The definition of a normal topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space) uses the concept of a neighborhood of a closed set. As you can see by reading through the page linked, it uses both the more restricted terminology of an "open neighborhood", as suggested by @WilliamElliot, as well as the less restricted terminology of a "neighborhood".

Comment: @LeeMosher, In my opinion the two definitions are not the same thing

Comment: Then when you write about neighborhoods, express your opinion carefully to make it clear what *you mean* by different variations of the terminology.

Comment: But I'll repeat my earlier advice in different words: when you *read* about neighborhoods, make sure you understand what *that author* means.

Comment: @LeeMosher, thanks, do you know why the first statement holds? do you know the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, your second box is not a "definition". In order to "prove" the statement in the first box, one needs a definition:

> **Definition of neighborhood**: Given a topological space $X$, a subset $S \subset X$, and a subset $V \subset X$, to say that $V$ is a neighborhood of $S$ means that there exists an open subset $U \subset X$ such that $S \subset U \subset V$. Given a point $x \in X$ and a subset $V \subset X$, to say that $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ means that $V$ is a neighborhood of $\{x\}$; equivalently, there exists an open subset $U \subset X$ such that $x \in U \subset V$.

Here's a proof of the first statement.

For the "only if" direction, suppose that $V \subset X$ is a neighborhood of $S$, so there exists an open subset $U \subset X$ such that $S \subset U \subset V$. Choose $x \in S$. It follows that $x \in U \subset V$. So $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

For the "if" direction, suppose that $V$ is a neighborhood of each $x \in S$, so there exists an open $U_x \in X$ such that $x \in U_x \subset V$. It follows that the set $U$ which is defined by $U = \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x$ is an open subset of $X$, and clearly $S \subset U \subset V$, and therefore $V$ is a neighborhood of $S$.

Comment: In your second line of the yellow box I think it should be $V \subset X$ instead of  $V \subset S$

Comment: Also I think we don't need to have $\color{green}{U = \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x}$, for example take the real line as the topological space and let $V=\left[-2,2\right]$ and  $U=\left[-1.5,1.5\right]$, also $S=\left[-1,1\right]$ now if we define $$U_x:\left[-0.1+x,x+0.1\right]$$ , here since for every $x$ we have $x∈U_x$ then $$S= \bigcup_{x \in S} x⊆ \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x⊆V$$,  as you see we don't have the equality $\color{green}{U = \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x}$ since $$\left[-0.1+x,x+0.1\right]\ne\left[-1.5,1.5\right]\tag{ for every $x∈S$}$$ , if I'm wrong please tell me , and thank you for your post.

Comment: sorry, we should have $U_x=(-0.1+x,x+0.1)$ since it should be an open set

Comment: That's right. And the set $U = \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x$ is open because, in any topology, any union of open sets is also an open set.

Comment: And thanks for the correction.

Comment: Keep in mind, the set $U$ is *defined* by that equation; I rewrote the "if" direction to clarify that point.

Comment: why we require to define the set $U$ as you said? , I mean regardless of the definition of $U$ we always can say that $V$ is a neighborhood of $S$ (in my opinion having the definition  $U = \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x$  or not having that does not concern the proof)

Comment: To prove that $V$ is a neighborhood of $S$ requires the **existence** of an open set $U$ such that $S \subset U \subset V$. To prove existence of  the set $U$, you must first define $U$, or give a formula for $U$, or otherwise describe the set $U$ in some specific manner, and then use the definition or formula or specification to **prove** that $S \subset U \subset V$. Did you have some other definition or formula or specification of $U$ in mind?

Comment: well I define $U$ such that $ \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x ⊆U $, then I think we have the result

Comment: That is not a formula for $U$, it is not a specification of $U$, it is merely a property that some values of $U$ may satisfy and other values of $U$ do not satisfy. $U = $WHAT?

Comment: you said it's a property that some values of $U$ may satisfy and the others don't satisfy , but I can't find any example that my characterization does not satisfy the property, have you any example?

Comment: Having answered the question in your post, and not having anything further to say in an extended discussion, I'll sign off on this comment chain. If you have further questions on the set theory and logic that underlies this and other topology proofs, formulating them in a new post would be a better use of the math.stackexchange site.